# Next.js warning on console: "Prop 'style' did not match"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am building website with Next.js. But I can see a red color warning from console and not sure the reason of it. It is related to **Image** component from **'next/Image'**

I want to remove this warning for the project's completeness. I attach my screenshot of the issue:

[image]

I added `<Image>` component to my Next.js and it is from `'next/Image'` and it throws red color's warning and I want to remove it.

Comment: Could you get the text representation of this error and paste it into your question, using the code formatting tool? Images of text are not as useful as the text themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**As per this discussion on Official NextJS Github page**

[How do I remove warning "Warning: Prop style did not match" when I import Image component in nextjs? #40648](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/40648)
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/40648

Are you using any extensions in your browser, they might inject some CSS code in your page for providing their functionality, **disable extensions & refresh your page**.